# PDO #1054 Unknown column 'n' in 'where clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, where-clause

I have a class with a function that will pull out any data from the database whatever the identifying column may be, which basicly looks like this

```
    use Database\DB;

class General extends DB
{   
    private $fooBar;

    public function getData($column, $table, $value) {
        $column = (array) $column;
        $column = implode(', ', $column);
        $test = $this->query("SELECT `$column` FROM `$table` WHERE $column[0] = :value", array("value" => $value));
    }

}
```

and is executed as following:

```
return $this->general->getData(['name'], 'people', 'John Anderson');
```

However, I'm getting an error which tells me there is an non-existent column input with the value 'n' (which is happening to be the first character of the column name, whatever the column name's value is)

Full error;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'n' in 'where clause'' in a\long\path\DB.class.php on line 50

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'n' in 'where clause' in a\long\path\DB.class.php on line 50
```

Thanks in advance,
Jordi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the line

```
$column = implode(', ', $column);
```

It's replacing the array with a string containing all the column names separated by comma. Then `$column[0]` will be the first character of the first column name, instead of the first column name.

Answer (score 0):

Put down your full query here.. Than it's easier!

**Edit:**

try this code:

```
use Database\DB;

class General extends DB
{   
    private $fooBar;

    public function getData($column, $table, $value) {
        $columns = (array) $column;
        $column = implode(', ', $columns);
        $test = $this->query("SELECT `$column` FROM `$table` WHERE $columns[0] = :value", array("value" => $value));
    }

}
```

I changed the following:
`$column = (array) $column;` to `$columns = (array) $column;`

And

```
SELECT `$column` FROM `$table` WHERE $column[0] = :value", array("value" => $value)
```

to

```
SELECT `$column` FROM `$table` WHERE $columns[0] = :value", array("value" => $value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it (see @Barmar answer as well):

(Take note of the difference in the implode statement as well).

```
use Database\DB;

class General extends DB
{   
    private $fooBar;

    public function getData($column, $table, $value) {
        $column = (array) $column;
        $whereCol = $column[0];
        $column = implode('`, `', $column);
        $test = $this->query("SELECT `$column` FROM `$table` WHERE $whereCol = :value", array("value" => $value));

        return $test;
    }

}
```

Comment: @JordiPrevost var dump the query itself? What does it give?

Comment: wasn't returning the query, lol. It gives me an empty now instead

Comment: No i mean how does the full raw query look like?
Because maybe it returns NULL or empty because there are no rows to return (that match)?